# Is there a way to fail a stage which doesn't log anything for X minutes in Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline which runs multiple stages in parallel.

I am looking for a way to log each stage individually (kind of like in Blue Ocean) and monitor the stage log to see if it got stuck. Sometimes we have scripts that get stuck, or other java/groovy code that is running and remains stuck without necessarily throwing an exception.

So I need to fail a stage if it doesn't log something for like 10 minutes. I tried to find if there is a way to live monitor the console log programmatically, but I couldn't find any.

I was thinking to have every stage also log to a file and check for the "lastModifiedDate" of that file. So I went and did a `tee` like this:

```
stage('Test') {
  steps {
    script {
      tee ("${WORKSPACE}/logs/${STAGE_NAME}.log"){
        echo "TEST"
        sleep(15)
        echo "Done"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works and creates a log file. 
Now I wanted to poll that directory and check to see if the file has been modified, otherwise failing the stage. 
For this I used some Groovy code, based on Java's Watch Service (which is documented more in depth here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html):

```
private void watchDirectory(String directoryToWatch) {
    Path path = Paths.get(directoryToWatch)
    WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()
    boolean poll = true
    boolean failed = false
    long lastModified = System.currentTimeMillis()
    while (poll) {
        WatchKey key = path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY)
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            Path changed = (Path) event.context()
            if (changed.endsWith("${STAGE_NAME}.log")) {
                println("My file has changed")
                lastModified = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastModified > 20000) {
            println("20 seconds")
            watchService.close()
            failed = true
            break
        }
        poll = key.reset();
    }

    if (failed) {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            sh "exit 1"
        }
    }
}
```

This groovy code works on my local machine, but used in Jenkins throws an exception at `line 8: WatchKey key = path.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY):`

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /data/jenkins/workspace/build_name/logs
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
  at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.asIOException(UnixException.java:111)
  at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.implRegister(LinuxWatchService.java:246)
  at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.processRequests(AbstractPoller.java:260)
  at sun.nio.fs.LinuxWatchService$Poller.run(LinuxWatchService.java:329)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It seems to me like it cannot do it through the Jenkins custom Groovy interpreter. Or maybe I am doing something wrong.

So, is there a better solution to achieve this, if any?

Comment: Have you tried `timeout` step with parameter `activity: true`?

Comment: Although not perfect, it is similar to what I was looking for. I don't know how I missed it. It sometimes fails, but I will have to test more. I've also encountered this issue with it:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58752. Can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it?